# I cant import a flash builder 4.0 project into flash builder 4.5

Tags: project, flash-builder

We have a flex app and its correspoding SWC project which works great in flash builder 4.0, and we have imported it a bunch of times to a fresh installation no problem.

However, there doesnt seem to be any way to get it to import or run in FB 4.5.

First, the projects were checked out into:
    c:\dev\flash_ws\apitester (this is the flex project)
    c:\dev\flash_ws\flashAPI (this is just a bunch of actionscript and the swc project).

Now in FB4.5, I simply hit file->import flash builder project, chose c:\dev\flash_ws\apitester and it picks up the .actionScriptProperties or similar and loads the project.  But it only imports half the project - it has lost the flashapi part.  If I do the same thing in FB4.0, it picks up the flashapi library project too.

The second problem, is FB4.5 has NO option to import an existing library project, or link to it.  If  I go into project->properties->library path, neither "add project" "add swc folder" nor "add swc" will take the directory  c:\dev\flash_ws\flashAPI which contains the source I want to be able to edit and use.

I notice that in source path is this:
    ${DOCUMENTS}\flashAPI\src

So it did remember the dependency on flashAPI

BUT: when I lookat project->properties->Resource->linked resoures, I see a load of rubbish:

```
DOCUMENTS->C:\Users\Simon\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5
PARENT_LOC->C:\Users\Simon\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5
PROJECT_LOC->C:\Users\Simon\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5
WORKSPACE_LOC->C:\Users\Simon\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5
```

I never chose these locations - flash did it by iteslf.

My workspace is in c:\dev\flash_ws.

I cant change the above! the Edit field is greyed out for all except DOCUMENTS.

So I changed DOCUMENTS to be  c:\dev\flash_ws, but it still doesnt pick up my flashAPI library.

Also, none of my mxml files are lised in the run configuratinos - its lost those, and I cant find a way to make flash builder realise that its own mxml files should be runnable.

Any ideas?

NB The project imports and runs fine in flashdevelop - which is free.  Thats what Im using until we can find away to get a flash builder project to work in flash builder.